# LaTeX equivalent of <br><br><br> in HTML?

Tags: line-breaking

In HTML, all I would have to do is:

```html
This is line one
<br>.<br>.<br>
This is line two
```

to get the following output:

```
This is line one
.
.
This is line two
```

I've been playing around with `\\` and `\newline` but can't get it to work. Can someone provide a working example?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I found out I was doing it entirely wrong. I relied on extra line breaks to give me more vertical space. **`\baselineskip`** matches my needs better and gives the user more fine control.

Comment: No, that won't be correct. See my updated answer bellow.

Comment: Please note, that this code is wrong in HTML, too, as logically there are no lines to end. The correct solution in HTML probably includes the use of CSS, so HTML/CSS is quite similar to LaTeX in this regard.

Comment: Both are wrong. The correct solution is to leave the required amount of vertical space, eg \vspace*{3\baselineskip}.

<br> in HTML and \\ in LaTeX are *premature line-ends* used to terminate the line before its normal end-point.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

LaTeX is for professional typesetting and doesn't allow you the freedom of HTML. Two line breaks in a row don't make any sense for typography. If you want to add more vertical space using the optional argument of `\\[<extra vertical space to add>]`.  The distance of two lines is given by `\baselineskip`:

```
This is line one\\[2\baselineskip]
This is line two
```

You can also use `\bigskip` between paragraphs to add more vertical space between them. Note that there is a difference between line breaks and new paragraphs.

```
This is the last line of one paragraph.
\par% or empty line in the source code
\bigskip
This is the first line of the next paragraph.
```

Comment: Yes, this method is more elegant.

Comment: Why the false dichotomy between "professional typesetting" and "freedom" :)

Comment: @Aditya - Would you prefer, "LaTeX is for professional typesetting and doesn't encourage you to mess about"? :-)

Answer (score 16):

You should separate paragraphs with blank lines. If, occasionally, you want an extra separation between two paragraphs you should use one of the `\...skip` commands, for example:

```
\noindent
This is the first paragraph.

\bigskip\noindent
This is the second paragraph.
```

Note that you wont be willing to do that too often, except for the occasional case. If you want to suppress indentation in *all* your paragraphs in your document, and leave a larger space between them, then use the `parskip` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

This is the first paragraph.

This is the second paragraph.

\end{document}
```

If for some reason you really want “line breaks” (as opposed to “paragraph breaks”) then use `\\`, i.e.:

```
This is line one \\
. \\
. \\
This is line two
```

Comment: If those dots are just for show, and there's no content between the ``\\``s, then it won't work directly...but you can fix that by sticking an empty `\mbox{}` between them.

Comment: But if you are trying to leave empty space between two paragraphs and trying to fake it with line breaks, then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 12):

What is important to note is that `\\` is for a premature line-break *within* a paragraph: it does *not* terminate the paragraph.

To add manual space *between* paragraphs, use `\par\vspace{<dimen>}`.

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, the equivalent in ConTeXt is `\blank[3*line]`. For example:

```
\starttext
One line
\blank[3*line]
2nd line
\stoptext
```

If you want a skip equal to bigskip, you can use `\blank[big]`; to get twice the bigskip, use `\blank[2*big]` etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
This is line one
.\par.\par
This is line two
```

or

```
This is line one
.

.

This is line two
```

an empty line is the same as `\par`. Only in *special* cases a `\\` makes sense instead of `\par`

Comment: The HTML equivalent of `<br>` *is* `\\ `, `\par` would be more like the closing of a `</p>`

Comment: I'm intrigued. To be honest, I always used `\\ ` instead of `\par`. Could you mention one of the special cases for `\\ `?

Comment: @Paulo: In running text you normally never have manual line breaks just paragraph breaks. I use ``\\`` (outside `tabulars` etc.) normally only when I have to stack two diagrams or images or something similar.

Comment: @Paulo: writing poems, tabular lines, equation lines. But not inside normal text that should always be paragraphs, divided by an empty line or a `\par`. It is really difficult for TeX to do a proper garapgraph formatting if you use ``\\``

Comment: Thanks @Martin and @Herbert. It's clear to me now. `=)`

Comment: @Juan: a lot of users use the `<br>` tag in a wrong way where also `<p> .. </p>` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *bigbreak*:

```
This is line one
\bigbreak.\bigbreak.\bigbreak
This is line two
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP was asking for. As artiin mentions, there is a difference between a linebreak and a paragraph brreak.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code.

```
This is line one\\\\[15pt]
Thia ia line two.
```

Note: `\\\\[15pt]` is a kind of line break that will let you simplify how long is your line break is. You can change 15 with any number you need.

Comment: Your answer repeats the answer by Martin Scharrer.

Comment: And you don't need four backslashes. Two is fine.